# Show that $M$ is R-orientable for any commutative ring $R.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, orientation

Show that if $M$ is a closed, connected and orientable manifold, then $M$ is $R-$orientable for any commutative ring $R.$

I got the following hint (Which I do not know how it will help me in the solution):

The advantage of using cohomology than homology is that cohomology have ring structure whch is not found in homology.

Could anyone give me a hint for solving that question please?

> [image]

Comment: Can you specify what is your definition of $R$-orientable?

Comment: @William I will edit my question with my definition.